# Populating listview from 2 tables SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I want to populate a listview from 2 tables in SQLite database. The listview will consist of 3views: an imageview and 2 textviews.

- 1st table: imageview and textview1
- 2nd table: textview2

I can successfully query data from one table and display it in a listview, but have no idea how to query from the 2nd one, then add it to the list. 
 The codes below displays a listview with data only from my_folders.
How can I change it such that textview1 shows data from table my_folders and textview2 shows data from my_expenses. Can anyone please help?

### This is mymain:

> public class mymain extends ListActivity {
>     ListView listContent;
>
> SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
>     final DBAdapter mySQLiteAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
>     Cursor cursor;
>
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>
> @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> ```
>
> //     setContentView(R.layout.list_example);
>
> ```
>   listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
>   final DBAdapter mySQLiteAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
>
>   mySQLiteAdapter.open();
>
>   cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllFolders();
>
>   String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.KEY_CURRENCY };
>   int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_row, R.id.notes_row };
>
>
>   cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor,
>           from, to);
>
>   setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
>   mySQLiteAdapter.close();
> ```
>
> }
>   }

### This my database:

```
import android.database.Cursor;

public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; 
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENCY = "currency";
    public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
    public static final String KEY_EXPENSE_NAME = "expense_name";
    public static final String KEY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT = "expense_amount";
    public static final String KEY_EXPENSE_DATE = "expense_date";
    public static final String KEY_EXPENSE_TIME = "expense_time";
    public static final String KEY_EXPENSE_NOTES = "expense_notes";
    public static final String KEY_EFOLDERID = "e_fid";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "my_folders";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "my_expenses";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_FOLDERS = 
        "create table my_folders (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "name text not null, currency text not null, notes text);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_EXPENSES = 
        "create table my_expenses (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "expense_name text not null, expense_amount real not null, " +
                    "expense_date text not null, expense_time text not null," +
                    "expense_notes text,"
        + "e_fid integer not null," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY ("+ KEY_EFOLDERID+ ") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLE1 +" ("+ >KEY_ROWID + ") ON DELETE CASCADE);";

    // ---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllFolders() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_CURRENCY, KEY_NOTES}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    // ---retrieves all the expenses---
    public Cursor getAllExpenses() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXPENSE_NAME,
                KEY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT, KEY_EXPENSE_DATE, KEY_EXPENSE_TIME, KEY_EXPENSE_NOTES, >KEY_EFOLDERID}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get the data from the 2 tables is to use a join query, something like

```
SELECT name, expense_name, expense_notes
FROM my_folders, my_expenses
WHERE my_folders._id = my_folders.e_fid
```

This will return all the data in 1 Cursor and which you can then put in your view